# Crop image sizes directly from Media Library across network (not attached to post or page but sidebar)

Tags: multisite, images, library

I have a MU network setup and I'm pulling in media library images and displaying 4 of those images randomly from across the entire network.

I've seen a few people on here using similar codes to do the same thing, my questions is:

**How do I crop images pulled directly from the media library dynamically?**

Currently the code works however it merely scales the image size and on right click > view image it shows the image in full size and not as a cropped thumbnail etc.

This obviously boosts the page size if each image is 5mb (x4 = 20mb) which is unnecessary, here is the code:

```
function get_images_from_media_library() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
        );
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= $image->guid;
    }
    return $images;
}

function display_images_from_media_library() {
    $imgs = get_images_from_media_library();
    $html = '<div id="media-gallery">';
    $html .= '<h3>Oriel / Gallery</h3>';
    foreach($imgs as $img) {
        $html .= '<img src="' . $img . '"/>';
    }
    $html .= '<h4><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/gallery">Weld mwy o / View more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></h4>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$images[]= wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'thumbnail')
```

Or define a new image size in functions.php

[add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I attempted using add_image_size() however it wasn't cropping it, the code pulls the images straight from the image library and not a post or page, I'm assuming that's why it's not able to crop it.

I also attempted the first option, just returns the array however I'll play with that more and see if I can get something to come out cropped.

Comment: Have you tried thumbnail? I don't use multisite much; the size could be being defined in the wrong place if mutisite uses themes differently. Also, have you flushed your image sizes? when you add a new size you'll need to regenerate all images on the site, this plugin is useful for that: http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Yeah I'm purging and regenerating the thumbnails as I go but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this using the standard thumbnails and image_sizes.

    <?php echo display_images_from_media_library(); ?>
 
 That's currently how I'm calling the code I posted above